# readJSON and readYaml stopped working in Jenkins after Jenkins Update

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed Pipeline Utility Steps plugin in my Jenkins and I used to use **readJSON** and **readYaml** without any issue.

A month later when I tried it i am getting the following error for both of them

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.readJSON() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[file:/data/ecsnames/dev_ECSNames.json]]
```

The error is similar for readYaml step as well.

I am not sure how it suddenly stopped working. Only thing I got from one of my teammates is that Jenkins was Updated to 2.235.5 version couple of weeks ago.

I used the following command

```
def clstrndsrvcnme = readJSON file: "/data/ecsnames/dev_ECSNames.json"
```

can anyone help me with this? And what does this error means?

**Update***

So I was trying the above command at **JenkinsURL/script**. There is a little IDE to run groovy scripts. I do all kinds of Debug there.
At that location it was throwing the error.

But when I am running the same commands from a Jenkins Job, it is working perfectly fine and i am able to read values from Yaml and Json. So what I believe is that somehow **JenkinsURL/script** is not able to use Pipeline Utility Scripts plugin.

I am able to do my work but still wanted to understand why it is failing here **JenkinsURL/script**.

Comment: could you double check if the pipeline utility plugin wasn't uninstalled by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent most of a day on this same problem. This fails in the Script Console:

```java
def jstring = '{"one":1, "two":2}'
def jobj = readJSON text: jstring
```

Thanks to your post, I tried it in a test pipe and it works:

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('readjson') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def jstring = '{"one":1, "two":2}'
                    def jobj = readJSON text: jstring
                    echo jobj.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
 [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
 [Pipeline] node
 Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\readJSON
 [Pipeline] {
 [Pipeline] stage
 [Pipeline] { (readjson)
 [Pipeline] script
 [Pipeline] {
 [Pipeline] readJSON
 [Pipeline] echo
 {"one":1,"two":2}
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // script
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // stage
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 Finished: SUCCESS
```

I've logged an issue in the Jenkins Jira for this plugin: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65910

I'll update this post with any responses from Jenkins.